# Is there an efficient way of returning data based on who is currently logged in through uid?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react-redux application with Firebase as the backend. The app lets a user create an account and in the process create a company and user_role. The user role contains the user_id and company_id. I would like to sync the company_data only where the user_role matches the uid.

I connect to firestore like so:

```
  firestoreConnect( props => [
      { collection : 'company_roles', where: [["user_id", "==", props.auth.uid]]  }
      { collection : 'company' },
  ]) 


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        auth: state.firebase.auth,
        company_data : state.firestore.ordered.company,
        company_roles : state.firestore.ordered.company_roles,
    }
}
```

and map state to props like so:

This returns the role that matches the uid as an array [{}] of just one object. Now when I try to return the company based on the user_role, it returns undefined. I do that like so:

```
{ collection : 'company', where: [["company_name", "==", props.company_roles.uid]]  },
```

I am stuck. what to do or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually common practice to store user data in Firestore collection called users where each user document is named per the users UID.
Looking at Javascript examples:

```js
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then((snapshot) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

You can read more about it here: [Firestore - Get Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Just make sure you also get familiar with Firestores [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

If you need granular control the above can be ideal, but for more generalized purposes you can implement [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims). This does however require the [Admin-SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin) and a server environment to run, most likely [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) which does require the Blaze Plan.